# Doctrine2 Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, polymorphism

I try to create a Many To Many Polymorphic Relations with Doctrine2 in Symfony2.

I would like a single entity that is associate dynamically with multiples entities.

I want to get this following schema:

1. **posts**

   - id: integer,
   - name: string

======

2. **videos**

   - id - integer
   - name - string

======

3. **tags**

   - id - integer
   - name - string

======

4. **taggables**

   - tag_id - integer
   - taggable_id - integer
   - taggable_type - string

In taggables entity :

- *tag_id*  is the of the associate tag
- *taggable_id*  is the id of associate post
- *taggable_type* is the type of associate entity ie 'Posts"

And I would like it to be the same with the "video" where:

- *tag_id*  represents the id of associate tag
- *taggable_id*  is the id of associate videos
- *taggable_type*  is the name of associate entity ie 'Videos'

and all this without duplicating table.

i'ved test multiple solutions but i never got this result :/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use only 3 tables? I suggest you to set-up `posts`, `videos` and `tags` tables, then use ManyToMany relations between posts and tags, and videos and tags.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with OOP, using inheritance.

Define an `abstract class Taggable`, and make `Post` and `Video` extend that class. Then create a OneToMany from `Tag` to `Taggable`.

Doctrine will take care of everithing, supposed that you choose between Single Table Inheritance or Class Table Inheritance.

I would choose Class Table, though.

More on this subject [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).